# Responsive menu script ignores the submenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script for a responsive menu to toggle the height:

```
       jQuery(function() {  
            var pull        = jQuery('#pull');  
                menu        = jQuery('nav ul');  
                menuHeight  = menu.height();  

            jQuery(pull).on('click', function(e) {  
                e.preventDefault();  
                menu.slideToggle();  
            });  
        }); 
        jQuery(window).resize(function(){  
            var w = jQuery(window).width();  
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
                menu.removeAttr('style');  
            }  
        });
```

The problem is that the nested unordered list's height is not taken into account and it just "pops" in and ruins the effect.  The HTML markup would be:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can see it live at http://www.windycitydigital.net/iconvert. Anyone have any idea how I could prevent that nested UL from ruining the toggle animation and making it all one fluid transition?

Comment: you're missing two `var`s or `,` Make your choice

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sure, see the menu *variable*? you're missing a comma  in the upper line instead of `;` or a `var` before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things could be useful here:

With the selector you've got there for menu it's going to select both the top level ul as well as any subnav ul...

Try changing that selector to this:

```
menu = jQuery('nav > ul')
```

This selector will select only direct child ul's of the nav element, and prevent the slideToggle function from firing on your subnav ul, which looks to include a display block on it in your CSS, styled by the following selector:

```
#navigation ul ul
```

Slidetoggle is going to toggle that to display: none with the selector you're currently using.

I'd also strongly consider changing your selectors to be a little cleaner, and more precise:

```
#navigation > ul
```

This will select *only* direct children of the navigation element. Using this selector instead of #navigation ul allows you to use less CSS since you don't have to override styles you've applied for your subnav elements by using the more general #navigation ul selector (which, as you've seen, affects every ul within #navigation).

Since you've applied a class to your sub-nav ul, you can style it directly using:

```
#navigation .sub-menu
```

Hopefully this helps steer you in the right direction!

!! Edit (after comment below) !!

Try this JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function() {  
    var pull        = jQuery('#pull'), 
        menu        = jQuery('.menu', '#navigation');  

    pull.on('click', function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();  
        menu.slideToggle('medium');
    });  
});
```

Oh, and make sure you change the #navigation ul { display: none } to #navigation > ul { display: none }, otherwise the problem mentioned above where the subnav hides will persist...

Comment: The display block was added as me trying to fix something. I actually removed that.  I want the toggle to fire away at the subnav as well, but I don't want it do just "appear," I would like it to be part of the transition.

Comment: That makes the toggle work well, but the subnav isn't displayed at all now. Is there a way to make the subnav part of the animation and open with it?

Comment: See the comment below the JS about making sure the display none is only applied to the #navigation > ul element, instead of all #navigation ul elements